# How to update a Collection in Many-Many by assigning a new Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In entity framework core 2.0, I have many-many relationship between `Post` and `Category` (the binding class is `PostCategory`).

When the user updates a `Post`, the whole `Post` object (with its `PostCategory` collection) is being sent to the server, and here I want to reassign the new received Collection `PostCategory` (the user may change this Collection significantly by adding new categories, and removing some categories).

Simplified code I use to update that collection (I just assign completely new collection):

```
var post = await dbContext.Posts
    .Include(p => p.PostCategories)
    .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Category)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(someId);

post.PostCategories = ... Some new collection...; // <<<
dbContext.Posts.Update(post);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**This new collection has objects with the same Id of objects in the previous collection (e.g. the user removed some (but not all) categories)**. Because of the, I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'PostCategory' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CategoryId', 'PostId'} is already being tracked.

How can I rebuild the new collection (or simply assign a new collection) efficiently without getting this exception?

#### UPDATE

[The answer in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993860/entity-framework-core-update-many-to-many) seems to be related to what I want, but it is a good and efficient method? Is there any possible better approach?

#### UPDATE 2

I get my post (to edit overwrite its values) like this:

```
public async Task<Post> GetPostAsync(Guid postId)
{
    return await dbContext.Posts
        .Include(p => p.Writer)
            .ThenInclude(u => u.Profile)
        .Include(p => p.Comments)
        .Include(p => p.PostCategories)
            .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Category)
        .Include(p => p.PostPackages)
            .ThenInclude(pp => pp.Package)
        //.AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == postId);
}
```

#### UPDATE 3 (The code in my controller, which tries to update the post):

```
var writerId = User.GetUserId();
var categories = await postService.GetOrCreateCategoriesAsync(
    vm.CategoryViewModels.Select(cvm => cvm.Name), writerId);

var post = await postService.GetPostAsync(vm.PostId);
post.Title = vm.PostTitle;
post.Content = vm.ContentText;

post.PostCategories = categories?.Select(c => new PostCategory { CategoryId = c.Id, PostId = post.Id }).ToArray();

await postService.UpdatePostAsync(post); // Check the implementation in Update4.
```

#### UPDATE 4:

```
public async Task<Post> UpdatePostAsync(Post post)
{
    // Find (load from the database) the existing post
    var existingPost = await dbContext.Posts
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == post.Id);

    // Apply primitive property modifications
    dbContext.Entry(existingPost).CurrentValues.SetValues(post);

    // Apply many-to-many link modifications
    dbContext.Set<PostCategory>().UpdateLinks(
        pc => pc.PostId, post.Id,
        pc => pc.CategoryId,
        post.PostCategories.Select(pc => pc.CategoryId)
    );

    // Apply all changes to the db
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return existingPost;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework core update many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993860/entity-framework-core-update-many-to-many)

Comment: @DanielB, Thank you. I already mentioned that in the update of the question.

Comment: notice you did not include the navigation property. I am not quite certain how changetracking would handle the setting of a navigation property (and I can't try it out right now) but I doubt it would work. You could try setting the state of each object (in prev. navigation property and new navigation property), but this would be tedious and error prone, so I'd suspect the given answer is the best approach.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, thank you, you are right, I just wrote the code here on the fly. I added the `include` to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main challenge when working with disconnect link entities is to detect and apply the added and deleted links. And EF Core (as of the time of writing) provides little if no help to do that.

The answer from the link is ok (the custom `Except` method is too heavier for what it does IMO), but it has some traps - the existing links has to be retrieved in advance using the eager / explicit loading (though with EF Core 2.1 lazy loading that might not be an issue), and the new links should have only FK properties populated - if they contain reference navigation properties, EF Core will try to create new linked entities when calling `Add` / `AddRange`.

A while ago I answered similar, but slightly different question - [Generic method for updating EFCore joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782491/generic-method-for-updating-efcore-joins/48827070#48827070). Here is the more generalized and optimized version of the custom generic extension method from the answer:

```
public static class EFCoreExtensions
{
    public static void UpdateLinks<TLink, TFromId, TToId>(this DbSet<TLink> dbSet,
        Expression<Func<TLink, TFromId>> fromIdProperty, TFromId fromId,
        Expression<Func<TLink, TToId>> toIdProperty, IEnumerable<TToId> toIds)
        where TLink : class, new()
    {
        // link => link.FromId == fromId
        Expression<Func<TFromId>> fromIdVar = () => fromId;
        var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TLink, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(fromIdProperty.Body, fromIdVar.Body),
            fromIdProperty.Parameters);
        var existingLinks = dbSet.AsTracking().Where(filter);

        var toIdSet = new HashSet<TToId>(toIds);
        if (toIdSet.Count == 0)
        {
            //The new set is empty - delete all existing links 
            dbSet.RemoveRange(existingLinks);
            return;
        }

        // Delete the existing links which do not exist in the new set
        var toIdSelector = toIdProperty.Compile();
        foreach (var existingLink in existingLinks)
        {
            if (!toIdSet.Remove(toIdSelector(existingLink)))
                dbSet.Remove(existingLink);
        }

        // Create new links for the remaining items in the new set
        if (toIdSet.Count == 0) return;
        // toId => new TLink { FromId = fromId, ToId = toId }
        var toIdParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TToId), "toId");
        var createLink = Expression.Lambda<Func<TToId, TLink>>(
            Expression.MemberInit(
                Expression.New(typeof(TLink)),
                Expression.Bind(((MemberExpression)fromIdProperty.Body).Member, fromIdVar.Body),
                Expression.Bind(((MemberExpression)toIdProperty.Body).Member, toIdParam)),
            toIdParam);
        dbSet.AddRange(toIdSet.Select(createLink.Compile()));
    }
}
```

It uses a single database query to retrieve the exiting links from the database. The overhead are few dynamically built expressions and compiled delegates (in order to keep the calling code simplest as possible) and a single temporary `HashSet` for fast lookup. The performance affect of the expression / delegate building should be negligible, and can be cached if needed.

The idea is to pass just a single existing key for one of the linked entities and list of exiting keys for the other linked entity. So depending of which of the linked entity links you are updating, it will be called differently.

In you sample, assuming you are receiving `IEnumerable<PostCategory> postCategories`, the process would be something like this:

```
var post = await dbContext.Posts
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(someId);

dbContext.Set<PostCategory>().UpdateLinks(pc => 
    pc.PostId, post.Id, pc => pc.CategoryId, postCategories.Select(pc => pc.CategoryId));

await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Note that this method allows you to change the requirement and accept `IEnumerable<int> postCategoryIds`:

```
dbContext.Set<PostCategory>().UpdateLinks(pc => 
    pc.PostId, post.Id, pc => pc.CategoryId, postCategoryIds);
```

or `IEnumerable<Category> postCategories`:

```
dbContext.Set<PostCategory>().UpdateLinks(pc => 
    pc.PostId, post.Id, pc => pc.CategoryId, postCategories.Select(c => c.Id));
```

or similar DTOs / ViewModels.

Category posts can be updated in a similar manner, with corresponding selectors swapped.

**Update:** In case you a receiving a (potentially) modified `Post post` entity instance, the whole update procedure cold be like this:

```
// Find (load from the database) the existing post
var existingPost = await dbContext.Posts
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == post.Id);

if (existingPost == null)
{
    // Handle the invalid call
    return;
}

// Apply primitive property modifications
dbContext.Entry(existingPost).CurrentValues.SetValues(post);

// Apply many-to-many link modifications
dbContext.Set<PostCategory>().UpdateLinks(pc => pc.PostId, post.Id, 
    pc => pc.CategoryId, post.PostCategories.Select(pc => pc.CategoryId));

// Apply all changes to the db
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Note that EF Core uses separate database query for eager loading related collecttions. Since the helper method does the same, there is no need to `Include` link related data when retrieving the main entity from the database.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you to edit the answer to show how you you use this code with a service layer (I just could not manage to find a clean way to do this)? (i.e., sending an entire `Post` entity (maybe tracked entity, which has some edited values, including these new many-many collection) from the `PostsController` to `PostService`),

Comment: You are welcome. But I'm afraid what you asking falls outside the scope of a SO answer. It's the asker responsibility to provide concrete usage cases which has to be covered. The way question is formulated currently, there is nothing I can add. The answer is just covering a specific aspect of the applying disconnected entity modifications - many-to-many link table with no additional fields. Applying main entity data modifications can be done in at least two different ways. Applying one-to-many child collection modifications is another story.

Comment: Apply all that recursively in a generic fashion is … almost impossible. AFAIK the only library that tried to address all that in EF6 was [GraphDiff](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff). There is similar EF Core extension - [Detached.EntityFramework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#detachedentityframework), but I haven't tried it so can't share opinion. The main point is - EF Core does not provide enough out of the box support for disconnected scenarios. Anyway, if you have troubles with concrete usage scenario, consider  posting another question describing it.

Comment: Anyway, included full update example in case I understood correctly the question from the comment :)

Comment: Thank you the core works, I accepted it, however, applying the new primitive values does not work. I get this exception: *System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'PostCategory' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'PostId', 'CategoryId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached*. This is I have now two tracked version of the entity. How can I solve it without using AsNoTracking. So by really passing a passed entity.

Comment: That's strange because primitive values are excluding the navigation properties. So the `Post` primitive properties has nothing in common with `PostCategory` shown in the exception. Looks like you are executing different code - like `Update` or `Add`? See, in controller calls the source is usually not an entity, and even it is, it's not supposed to be the entity attached to the context. The context is usually short lived (just for the call), and the goal is to update the database. Trying to keep the identity of the passed instance is hard and inefficient.

Comment: May be I'm missing the use case. The assumption is that `post` is not tracked by the `dbContext`. Because if it's tracked, then we don't need to do anything than calling `dbContext.SaveChanges()` - the change tracker will do everything for us.

Comment: I added how I am fetching the post, maybe I am doing something wrong here (UPDATE 2 in the question)?

Comment: This is quite different usage (I hate these repositories hiding what's going on). You first retrieve a tracked `Post` entity (which corresponds to my `originalPost` variable) with `post.PostCategories` eagerly loaded. Then the line `post.PostCategories = categories?.Select(c => new PostCategory { CategoryId = c.Id, PostId = post.Id }).ToArray();` destroys the tracking information for the original collection. With such usage, probably it would be better to use the method from the answer from the link, but expose special repository method for that where you can pass both old and new collection.

Comment: I used it inside the last method (I showed the details of it in UPDATE4, sorry for confusing you). I did not use you method inside the controller directly because I exposes dbContext only in the service layer, not in the controller, and I was trying to post only one single entity (post), to my update function, and every primitive and navigation property will be updated. So in this case it is not possible to pass tracked entity to my update function? Or is there any possible solution. If that was too much, I may open new question for that. (I could not understand what you mean in last sentence)

Comment: So I meant with a single pass of tracked post object, to a single function (to update both primitive and navigation properties).

Comment: I meant your **Update 3**. When you get a post with `postService.GetPostAsync(vm.PostId);` and set the primitive properties from the view model, all you need is to call a special method of the repository (which has access to the db context) passing the `currentItems` and `newItems` for the `TryUpdateManyToMany` method from the answer from the link in **Update 1**. Finally you have to somehow call `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`. No `UpdatePostAsync` method is needed at all in such scenario, because the `post` object is tracked.

Comment: If you want to use `UpfatePostAsync` method from the **Update 4**, then instead of `var post = await postService.GetPostAsync(vm.PostId);` inside controller (**Update 3**) use `var post = new Post { Id = vm.PostId };`.

Comment: But creating a new post using `new` word with only Id assigned, will leave all properties, that I do not explicitly assign, with their default value. So when I pass the object to the method (without explicitly assigning every property), the properties will be overwritten to their default value (at least I think so). That is why I did not created the object manually.

Comment: Ok, this is a closed circle. And the repositories instead of helping are creating troubles. The code that does what you need w/o repository is in the **Update** of my answer. Just instead of `dbContext.Entry(existingPost).CurrentValues.SetValues(post);` you set the `existingPost` properties from the passed view model. This is your goal, but I can't say how you can achieve the same with repository. To me (and not only, and your usage case is a good example of why), the repository pattern is redundant anti-pattern when used with EF (Core), which itself implements Repository and UOW.

Comment: I was thinking about the same idea, ok this is my last comment to wrap this up. I agree that repository pattern is redundant with EF, but this is actually a service layer (where my business login is written). Do you mean that I had to use the dbContext directly inside my Controller without this Service?

Comment: I don't know mate. All I can say is that definitely using directly the db context has no problems handling this and similar scenarios, while all repository pattern implementations I've seen seem to handle only simple scenarios with independent entity with no relations and fail with more complicated scenarios.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, your comments helped me to understand multiple things I did not understand correctly before.

Comment: @ivan will it works for many to many with additional column https://stackoverflow.com/q/63770379/8250886

Comment: @Glen Unfortunately no (at least directly) because it was built  around Ids only.

Comment: I did not find  any example of update many to many with additional column ? Is it possible directly we can update?(; without extension method)

Comment: @Glen Nothing out-of-the-box working for all scenarios. From the other side, since currently many-to-many is nothing more than 2 one-to-many, some of the one-to-many sync techniques (also not out-of the-box) can be used depending of what do you receive as input. For some examples see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63352197/update-parent-and-child-collections-on-tentity-generic-repository/63355308#63355308 and linked.